# Names of the galactic backdrop

Tags: milky-way, night-sky, nomenclature

I am wondering what are the various names given to the plane of the milky way. I am looking for a specific one I once heard, and will likely recognise when I see it.

If I can explain better with [a picture](https://www.pexels.com/photo/stars-1257860/), what are the various names of this bright band of dust and galactic-core:

[image]

I apologise if this is not an *astronomy* question. What subject would it fall under, if not? Certainly, I am not looking for astrological mumbo jumbo or anything.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the galaxy components known as the bulge, the thin disk, the thick disk, and the halo?

Comment: @pela I don't think so. It's not necessarily a technical name, iirc.

Comment: Wikipedia has a [list of names for the Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_names_for_the_Milky_Way), e.g. Straw Path, Silver River.

Comment: "great rift"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Rift_(astronomy)#:~:text=In%20astronomy%2C%20the%20Great%20Rift,galaxy%20from%20Earth's%20perspective.

Comment: @JamesK I think that might be it... Not sure. I'll leave the question open a while longer and if nothing better comes along I'll accept that as the answer (if you make it into one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The central part of the milky way has a *dark* band, the result of dust blocking out light from more distant stars.  This is sometimes called the "Great rift" or "dark rift".